# adding values from two arrays to one new one

Tags: jquery

i have two arrays tvpack[] and tvpackPrice[] how can i make one list with the

```
resultArray[] = "MySports <span class='price-montly'>19.00 $</span>",
                "Fun <span class='price-montly'>6.00 $</span>"
```

This is my code:

```js
var resultArray = [];
    $.each($("input[name='tvpack[]']:checked"), function() {
        resultArray.push($(this).val());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="circle-buttons">
<input type="checkbox" name="tvpack[]" id="sportpro" value="MySports">
<input type="hidden" name="tvpackPrice[]" id="sportproPrice" value="19.00 $">
<label for="sportpro">MySports
</label>
<div class="check"></div>
<span class="price">19.00</span>
</span>
<span class="circle-buttons">
<input type="checkbox" name="tvpack[]" id="fun" value="Fun">
<input type="hidden" name="tvpackPrice[]" id="funPrice" value="6.00 $">
<label for="plus">Fun 
</label>
<div class="check"></div>
<span class="price">6.00</span>
</span>
```

With this loops I only get values from the first array, I don't know how I can include the second array.

i need something like this:

```
 var resultArray = [];
    $.each($("input[name='tvpack[]']:checked"), function(i) {
        $.each($("input[name='tvpackPrice[]']"), function(j) {
            resultArray.push($(i, j).val());
        });
    });
```

Thanks to everyone for their help.

Comment: Have you tried adding another loop that loops through the tvpackPrice[] as it pushes to the resultArray?

Comment: @JamesShisiah I'm trying but I haven't succeeded yet, I don't work often with jquery so I don't know how to apply that code

Comment: Must you use the hidden attribute?
You can use the HTML data attribute to store the price, and just retrieve it in one loop
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp

Something like: 
<input type="checkbox" name="tvpack[]" id="sportpro" value="MySports" data-price="6.00 $">